# Why does <select> have blank <option> elements when populating from database?

Tags: php, html

I'm pulling data from a database to populate a  list:

```
<div class="data_input">
<form class="result_data">
<select name="results">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_data)){ 
  echo "<option value =\"result1\">" . $row{'result_name'} . "<option>";
} 
?>
</select>
```

The output is fine, except I can't figure out why I am getting a blank option in between records.

```
<select name="recipes">
<option value="result1">One</option>
<option></option>
<option value="result1">Two</option>
<option></option>
<option value="result1">Three</option>
<option></option>
<option value="result1">Four</option>
<option></option>
<option value="result1">Five</option>
<option></option>
<option value="result1">Six</option>
<option></option>
```

When I output the data in a simple list:

```
<ul>
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_data)){
        echo "<li>" . $row{result_name} . "</li>";
    }
?>
</ul
```

It comes out fine. No blank lines.

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Anyone have any tips on this?

NOTE: This question is not a duplicate question. It involves a mistake with an HTML tag.

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: you should also format this `$row{'result_name'}` like `$row['result_name']`

Comment: You're not closing your option tag. I suspect that the browser is "correcting" this by closing the tag for you and opening another empty one. Try correcting the second `<option>` to `</option>`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra eyes/tips.